# How to handle rating indicator when no one has rated yet?

Tags: website-design, feedback, ratings

My website is showing a rating for each product (up to 5).

```
----------------
| 4.2 average  |
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

The problem is that when no one has rated the product yet, if I put it can be interpreted as a very bad product (where some users have rated 0)

Comment: http://emptystat.es/

Answer (score 4):

put in a "be the first to rate this product"-indicator and/or mark it as "unrated".

I, personally, like to see the ratio - like youtube, amazon and others do. Either minimalistically by giving the number of total votes or by showing how many voted for what (thumbs up/down or 1-star, 2-star, ..).

Comment: Are you suggesting showing a ratio of 0:0 *as well as* the text of 'be the first to rate this product'?

Comment: Whatever floats your (customers) boat. I'd personally replace the 0.0 with "unrated" and tack on a "be the 1st"-bubble/box/whatever to the regular design (on the side, below or even floating above it).

Comment: I like the idea to  put in a "be the first to rate this product"

Comment: [Here's an visual example of @Flowtron's answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gWQuP.png)

Comment: I don't recommend showing 0/0 because it seems odd. Instead, I would just show "Be the first to rate this product" just as it were on Facebook with "Be the first to like this amongst your friends" sort of jargon.

Comment: @caribou.warbling I wouldn't use red though. It's so jarring, and implies there is an error of some sorts.